# FlatList scroll to top while FlatList in child component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am quite new to react native and would like to ask how to scroll to top when tap on button in a FlatList. However, in my case, the FlatList is inside a child component which I don't know how to pass the ref around.

I have tried createRef() in the parent component and pass it down to child component where the FlatList in. However, still getting error like **_this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex is not a function**

Here is what I have tried so far:
[link expo](https://snack.expo.io/@jasonkw-abc/flatlist-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following,

```
 _didTapOnButton=()=>{
   setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.timerFlatlistRef)
      this.timerFlatlistRef.scrollToIndex({
        animated: true,
        index: 0,
      });
  }, 1000);
 }

 _getItemLayout = (data, index) => ({
    length: 24,
    offset: 100 * index,
    index
 });

_renderItems = ({ item, index }) => {
 ...
 ...
}

...
<FlatList
     ref={ref => (this.timerFlatlistRef = ref)}
     style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 10 }}
     data={dayHours}
     getItemLayout={this._getItemLayout}
     renderItem={this._renderItems}
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
     extraData={this.state}
/>
...
```

Comment: Do I need to call _didTapOnButton in my parent component?

Comment: That is the button action for your purpose. You can call the scrollToIndex where you want.

Comment: I can just call this.timerFlatlistRef.scrollToIndex in my parent component?

Comment: Yes, please add a time delay.

Comment: Assuming your code is in child component. How would parent component get this.timerFlatlistRef? Sorry if this is a stupid question but I cant really understand.

Comment: You need to pass the reference to parent component via a callback function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202536/discussion-between-jebin-benny-and-jk9).

Comment: Thanks Benny, I've tried your suggestion and it works